Why is the offscreen canvas not adhering to backdrop-filter styling property
I have a project, in which I draw a canvas using a webworker. The drawing comes out fine. For the rest of the section's design, I have 4 cards, which I want them to apply a backdrop filter on the canvas. For some reason, the filter is partly affecting the canvas, but not giving me the desired effect.

As the picture above shows, the blur effect is being applied, but at the same time the canvas is shown from behind as if the filter wasn't applied at all.
For additional information, I have opened the "Layers" tab in DevTools to check out how Google Chrome renders those layers, and the layers' order seems fine, although, it seems like this singular offscreen canvas element creates 2 more that are not present in the DOM, with a slight change in their rendering resolution (original is 1320x600, the other 2 are 1323x600 and 1327x604).
Below is the JSX and CSS code used for those elements (written in react)
<div className="container">
   <div className="canvas-wrapper">
      <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
   </div>
   <div className="cards-container">
      <AnimatedCard header='header1'>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni possimus labore fugit impedit quaerat reiciendis hic velit laboriosam praesentium ad?
      </AnimatedCard>
      <AnimatedCard header='header2'>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni possimus labore fugit impedit quaerat reiciendis hic velit laboriosam praesentium ad?
      </AnimatedCard>
      <AnimatedCard header='header3'>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni possimus labore fugit impedit quaerat reiciendis hic velit laboriosam praesentium ad?
      </AnimatedCard>
      <AnimatedCard header='header4'>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni possimus labore fugit impedit quaerat reiciendis hic velit laboriosam praesentium ad?
      </AnimatedCard>
   </div>
</div>

.canvas-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    height: 100%;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: -100;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 6, 10, 1) 85%, transparent 95%);
    border-left: 1px solid var(--gray-border-color);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--gray-border-color;
    z-index: -10;
}

.cards-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(150px, 1fr));
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

// this is the background of the cards above
.card-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgba(var(--black-tint-3), 0.1);
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 32px 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}


That's a bug, introduced by this CL.
I opened a report, let's hope this gets fixed soon enough.
Of note, you don't even need to transfer the control to an OffscreenCanvas, a mere 2D context on the <canvas> directly will also reproduce the bug.
You can workaround it by specifying a transparent gradient backround-image on the <canvas> element1..
Below is a simple repro, with the workaround set through the checking of the checkbox:


const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
body {
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
  background-size: 2em 2em;
}
canvas-holder { display: block; backdrop-filter: blur(5px); }

label { background: white }
label:has(:checked) + canvas-holder canvas {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
}
<label><input type="checkbox"> Apply fix</label>
<canvas-holder>
  <canvas></canvas>
</canvas-holder>




1. It seems many other settings would prevent the bug, e.g. drawing a border  or an outline on the container, but the transparent background image seems to be the less intrusive.
